# How to filter a single character and delete it using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I end up deleting the element containing the character every time I try.

What I'm trying to delete is the comma for each `.date`:

```
<div class='date'>Nov 1, 2011</div>
<div class='date'>Dec 22, 2011</div>
```

Comment: Could you post the javascript you're using?

Comment: @Dave I was using jQuery and just found out that it can't delete matched characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var date0 = document.getElementsByClassName("date")[0];
var string = date0.innerHTML;
var newString = string.replace(/,/g,"");
date0.innerHTML = newString;
```

This should take the content of the first `.date` element, search for any commas, remove them, and put the updated string back into the element.

Here's some code that will remove the comma in all `.date` elements:

```
var date = document.getElementsByClassName("date");
var len = date.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var datei = date[i];
    var string = datei.innerHTML;
    var newString = string.replace(/,/g, "");
    datei.innerHTML = newString;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/bzxSN/).

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. I have to wait 4 minutes to accept the answer though

Comment: You should be using [nodeValue](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68D080) instead of innerhtml.